# What is the right way to save and modify and read a list of data for UWP app?

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to save a large list of data. I want to add a new entry but don't want to delete the entire list and save again. What do you recommend me for this solution? SQLite or Serialization or anything else ?

Answer (score 0):

The best option for this would be SQLite, because it allows you to add rows into your table without having to read the entire file as well as perform fast queries on your data. Great start into SQLite in UWP is in [this blogpost](http://www.shenchauhan.com/blog/2015/11/25/sqlite-and-uwp) or in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases) if you prefer to use Entity Framework Core.

Alternative would be having a text-file in application's local storage and just appending new data to it.

```
var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(
   "yourfile.txt",
   CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists); //just open the file if it already exists
await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, "some new text"); //add text
```